# Fatal Exception: main error in android using Sqlite Server

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

```
package com.example.track__trace;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    // private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "medical";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // you can use an alternate constructor to specify a database location
        // (such as a folder on the sd card)
        // you must ensure that this folder is available and you have permission
        // to write to it
        // super(context, DATABASE_NAME,
        // context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null,
        // DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public Cursor getEmployees() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = { "id", "dname" };
        String sqlTables = "mediv";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }

    public Cursor get(String str1) {
        // str1="Asthma";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect = { "id", "dname", "mname", "salt", "facts",
                "symptoms", "h_name", "cost" };
        // String [] sqlSelect1 = { "dname"};

        String sqlTables = "mediv";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);

        String squery = "select mname,salt, facts,symptoms,h_name,cost from mediv where dname=?";

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "dname=?", new String[] { str1 },
                null, null, null);
        // qb.q

        // c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }
}
```

---

here is the stack trace:

```
05-01 22:17:52.681
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id: , while compiling: SELECT id, dname, mname, salt, facts, symptoms, h_name, cost FROM mediv WHERE (dname=?)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:280)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.example.track__trace.MyDatabase.get(MyDatabase.java:60)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.example.track__trace.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-01 22:18:09.291: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 22:18:13.011: I/Process(305): Sending signal. PID: 305 SIG: 9
```

Please help me by giving soloution to this problem?
& also tell that whether i am using correct query or not?

Comment: Post your table creation query.

Comment: Please learn to work with database from here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Just guessing, try changing `id` to `_id` as it's usually [the default column name for ID in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID)

Answer (score 0):

As @vipul said plz post your table creation query...

Anyways i will try to answer your question :-

Things like that does happen if u created a db without id and later you added the create table with id but suppose you created  today without id and tomorrow with id then but since the table does exists it wont execute your create table query hence to be safe side and see from starting uninstall the app. Change the name of DB then install it again and see if it works.

But before that please check that id is in the create table query...

thx